# Got an issue while generating html report in jmeter 5.1.1v

Tags: jmeter

[image: useeproper][image: user properties file[![randomorder jtl file]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ve9Y.png)[[image: Generating html report]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2FnZ.png)

While generating html report getting an issue as jtl' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties could u please suggest me, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say what's wrong without seeing first 2 lines of the `RandomOrderController.jtl` file.

The error itself indicates inconsistency in [JMeter Results File configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), to wit your `RandomOrderController.jtl` file structure doesn't match what JMeter expects. Double check the way you're generating this .jtl results file, if you got it from test execution on another JMeter instance - make sure that all `jmeter.save.saveservice.*` properties are exactly the same.

The property responsible for storing header in .jtl results file is:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names
```

the possible values are `true` - print the header, and `false` - don't print it.

Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding htem.

Comment: Hi dmitri thanks for ur guidence ,i had provided screenshots of user properties and jtl of my script pls suggest me where i did mistake

Comment: As of now you can generate HTML dashboard only from CSV files, XML files are not supported.